# after clicking new Collapsible closed other Collapsible which is open

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-redux

// Here in my code there are three Collapsibles, after clicking one it will expand, but to close it again i have to click on that particular text.
I would like to make a change: if any of the three Collapsibles are already open, and I click the new button, then the existing Collapsibles should close automatically.

```
 {isSimUAllowed && <View style={styles.paymentMethod}>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                    this.setState({ simUpgrade: !this.state.simUpgrade });
                  }}>
                    <RegularText text="SIM Upgrade" textColor={this.state.simUpgrade?'#006288':'black'} style={{fontWeight:this.state.simUpgrade?'bold':'normal'}}/>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  <Collapsible collapsed={!this.state.simUpgrade}>
                    <Button
                      block
                      primary
                      onPress={() => this.loadScreen('CustomerVerification', 'swap',1)}
                      style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
                    >
                      <Text>Proceed</Text>
                    </Button>
                  </Collapsible>
                </View>}
                {isSimCAllowed && <View style={styles.paymentMethod}>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                    this.setState({ lostSim: !this.state.lostSim });
                  }}>
                     <RegularText text="SIM Change" textColor={this.state.lostSim?'#006288':'black'} style={{fontWeight:this.state.lostSim?'bold':'normal'}}/>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  <Collapsible collapsed={!this.state.lostSim}>
                    <Button
                      block
                      primary
                      onPress={() => this.loadScreen('CustomerVerification', 'lost',1)}
                      style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
                    >
                      <Text>Proceed</Text>
                    </Button>
                  </Collapsible>
                </View>}
                {isSimEAllowed && <View style={styles.paymentMethod}>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                    this.setState({ validator: !this.state.validator });
                  }}>
                   <RegularText text="E-validator" textColor={this.state.validator?'#006288':'black'} style={{fontWeight:this.state.validator?'bold':'normal'}}/>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  <Collapsible collapsed={!this.state.validator}>
                    <Button
                      block
                      primary
                      onPress={() => this.loadScreen('CustomerVerification', 'validate',0)}
                      style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
                    >
                      <Text>Proceed</Text>
                    </Button>
                  </Collapsible>
                </View>}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [`Accordion`](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible#accordion-usage) component from [`react-native-collapsible`](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible) takes care of this particular use case.